# Can we enable DDM on SQL Server 2016 using code first approach?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I am creating an application using .NET Core 2.1 along with SQL Server 2016. We can enable DDM for secure strings in SQL Server 2016. But I am using a code-first approach and want to enable DDM for my secure strings. Is there any way to do that?

Also I have another question is there any good need to use `SecureString` in .NET app instead of using hash functions on simple strings?

Comment: hashing a string doesnt erase it from memory. string are immutable..so simple string will still be there unless garbage collection happens

Comment: yeah, I also had the same understanding. Just wanted to confirm. Thanks